# how to get slider line on x axis and y axis for Chart in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I want two slider lines - one for x-axis and another for y-axis to show accurate result at any point in the line chart. As slider line move through the any axis it should display the crossing point values (display cross point values w.r.t. axis where slider line overlaps graph ) on the chart. Is there any method available for it ? If not how do I proceed for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just place a horizontal and vertical slider next to the charts. However, I'm assuming you want to use them like a scrollbar?

You might prefer using gestures like drag and pinch to work with charts.